# How to say that something is really important in general, but not as important as other things?

Tags: comparative-constructions, comparative

> Although learning a foreign language is really important, it plays a
> subordinate role in children's life compared with other components of education such as
> social skills, intellect and craftsmanship.

I accept that learning a foreign language is really important, but there are some other things that should be priority. I mean, learning a foreign language plays an important role  generally, but it plays a subordinate role when considering some other things such  as learning social skills. Is this meaningful to say so? Could you please suggest a perfect comparison construction if "compared with" is not suitable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally wouldn't use the word 'subordinate' in this context, but otherwise there's nothing wrong with your phrasing as far as I can see.

Some other ways to say this, using your example:

- Learning a foreign language is important, but not as important as other things, such as social skills.
- Learning a foreign language is important, but it is secondary to the importance of other skills like craftsmanship.
- Learning a second language is *important*, but things like socials skills and intellect are **vital.**
- Learning another language is important but learning basic skills like reading, writing and speaking are **paramount.**

If you say in a sentence that [thing A] is important, then go on to say 'but [thing B] is vital/paramount/more important', then the meaning is clear. Words like *vital* and *paramount* mean very important.

If there is one thing that's more important than anything else, you might say that this thing is of **utmost importance.**